# cellForRowAtIndexPath Usage Pattern

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uikit

In the below code I want to perform some DB actions when a cell is deleted, therefore I need to send my Server information about the cell being deleted. If I remember correctly cellForRowAtIndexPath should never be called directly, However I cannot think of any other way to get cell info in the below method, so my question is:

Is it acceptable to call cellForRowAtIndexPath manually below:

```
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]);



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        [localGlobalNotifications removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [notificationTableView beginUpdates];

        [notificationTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];



        [self postLeaveRequest];

        NSLog(@"Row is : %@", [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]);


        [notificationTableView endUpdates];

    }
}
```

To clarify: I understand that I can invoke a delegate call of cellForRowAtIndexPath by calling reloadData, what I'm trying to do is access the cell being deleted within commitEditingStyle. I'm not trying to reload my tableView, instead I want to get a reference to the cell being deleted. - Is it acceptable to obtain a reference to said cell by calling cellForRowAtIndexPath directly?

Comment: Do you override `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? If yes, paste the code here

Comment: Yes I do, and it's working perfectly. Also my above code is working, I just don't want to violate the iOS design paradigms. Is there a more elegant way to get a reference to the cell being deleted?

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to see how do you populate your `tableView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with asking the TableView to give you the cell, just as you do in your sample code.

Here's the documentation for the return value:

> An object representing a cell of the table or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range.

If you're annotating the cell with 'model' data then I think you're breaking the MVC pattern.  Your view doesn't need to know about the model data in this way, and so querying the view to make a database change will make life difficult you in the future (readability, extensibility and reusability for example)

You would be better off having your DB metadata stored in a collection such as an NSArray - or an NSArray of NSArrays.

Then you could get all the data you need with something like:

```
id modelData = myModel[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Indeed you are correct, I will move to a design like you suggest, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` as they have also used in apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageSelections/ManageSelections.html) or you can create an array of your cells then you can delete it from there and reflect it in your database.

Answer (score -1):

You can call cellForRowAtIndexPath: method using following line, here it will automatically calls all delegate and datasource methods.

```
   [tableView reloadData];
```

or

```
  [tableViewObjct reloadData];
```

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: Hi :) I understand that I can invoke a delegate call of cellForRowAtIndexPath by calling reloadData, what I'm trying to do is access the cell being deleted within commitEditingStyle. I'm not trying to reload my tableView, instead I want to get a reference to the cell being deleted. - Is it acceptable to obtain a reference to said cell by calling cellForRowAtIndexPath directly?